# I have 6 out of 5 days toward the Curious badge, but it has not yet been awarded. Why is that?

Tags: support, badges

In my badges, it says that I am 6/5 to earning the curious badge, and yet I don't have it. Why in the world does this happen?

Comment: Give it a day or so.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The full explanation of the Curious badge is as follows:

> Ask a well-received question on 5 separate days, and maintain a positive question record

While you meet the former, you do not meet the latter and the badge progress indicator should show this - here's what mine looks like here on Space Exploration (where I've not asked any questions):

[image: Small modal that is opened on hovering over the Curious badge on a user's profile if that's the selected "next badge". It reads "How do you earn this badge? Ask a well-received question on 5 separate days, and maintain a positive question record - 0/5 days asked - need positive question record"]

While it can be slightly confusing "maintain a positive question record" does actually mean something and that's the explanation for why you don't have the badge. It's not a bug, unfortunately, you just happen to have some questions that reduce your question record score below the threshold required to be considered "positive".

If you mark Curious as your next badge and hover over the badge to open the small modal as shown above, you will likely have the same indication that you need a positive question record.

If you're curious what your current status is, you can use the formula found in [this Meta Stack Exchange question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/251172/should-we-change-the-positive-asking-record-criteria-for-the-curious-badge-set) about the Curious badge on your own questions - note, you'll need to check any [deleted questions](https://space.stackexchange.com/users/deleted-questions/current) in addition to what shows up on your active questions list.

`(total questions - negative questions - closed - early deleted)/total questions >= 0.5`

In this, "early deleted" means questions deleted within 60 days of being asked.

Based on my math (which is sometimes questionable) your score currently is:

(41 questions - 6 negative questions - 17 closed - 4 early deleted) / 41 >= 0.5
(41 - 27) / 41 >= 0.5
14/41  >= 0.5
0.34 >= 0.5

Since your question record is 0.34 instead of 0.5 or higher, you do not currently qualify for the Curious badge. Note that closed, deleted and downvoted questions can count against you three times, so any questions in two or three categories can end up impacting your record by quite a lot.

For more information on this, please see the ["Question Badges" section](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/what-are-the-badges-i-can-earn-on-each-site-and-what-are-the-exact-criteria-for/67399#67399) of the giant MSE FAQ about the qualifying triggers for the various badges.

Comment: In depth, very nice!

Answer (score 2):

Various badges have different time thresholds when they are calculated. Please read the [FAQ pages on meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/1716/154443) for answers.

For your specific question, that page says:

> General rule: Wait at least 24 hours. If you haven't gotten it by then, you probably didn't meet the criteria for the badge, or you initially met them but ceased to meet them by the time the job ran. Try checking the list of all badges and their exact criteria. If you still didn't get awarded a badge after 24 hours and you've confirmed that you still continue to meet its criteria, go ahead and file a report, as at that point, chances are that the badge query is at fault, but it may also be that the badge query simply didn't run due to unlucky random chance.